# What does visible class list?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm a little bit confused with this.

```
 element.classList.add('visible');
```

In this example code, what does the 'visible' is that an event or what?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), [css classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors).

Comment: An element's "class" attribute can be controlled via classList. A class named "visibile" is a common pattern for defining CSS that lets you show and hide elements, e.g. your css says `aside { display: none; } aside.visible { display: block }`,and now toggling that class can be used to show/hide your aside.

Answer (score 1):

It it likely the name of a [css class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors).